# Verilog simple register testbench

Tags: verilog

I want to infer a simple flip flop using verilog.  Here is the code.

```
module tb_simpleRegister();

  reg clk;
  reg a;
  wire b;

  simpleRegister dut
  (
    .clk(clk),
    .a(a),
    .b(b),
    .c(c)
  );


  initial begin
    clk=1;
    a=0;
    #10
    a=1;
    #10
    a=0;
  end

  always #5 clk = ~clk;
endmodule

module simpleRegister(
    input clk,
    input a,
    output reg b,
    output reg c
    );

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        b <= a;
        c <= b;
    end
endmodule
```

And [here](http://pasteboard.co/2v2fH8WO.png) is the result when I run it. The b output of dut does not behave like a flip flop. However output c does. Any comments on why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean with "does not behave like a flip flop"? What is the intended result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rewrite the test bench as follows:

```
initial begin
    @(posedge clk);
    a<=0;
    @(posedge clk);
    a<=1;
    @(posedge clk);
    a<=0;
  end

//Clock in separate process
initial begin
  clk=1;
  forever begin
    #5 clk = ~clk;
  end
end
```

The non-blocking assignment will ensure the value of a is changed just after the clock edge giving the testbench a full cycle setup.

Comment: Thanks. Your code works fine. Also when I change my initial loop to   "initial begin
    clk=1;
    a<=0;
    #10
    a<=1;
    #10
    a<=0;
end"     it works.